# The Blam Image BackGround Not Showing in 3D View

Tags: camera, movie-clip-editor, blam

I'm Trying to use Blam but I cant see the Image background on CameraView, the one that I added in Movie Clip Editor and draw lines in X and V axis for mapping

Here is a screenshot of my blender

[image: Here is a screenshot of my blender]

did I change something that I don't remember or like that?
and sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

You must manually add the image.
press N to spaw the view properties menu in the 3D View - Object Mode. In there, locate a check box that reads, *Background Images* ( It's around the bottom). Drop it down and enable it. Click on add images, locate the photo you used in BLAM and you should have the image visible from the camera view.